# Duplicate block of code

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I'm using vim a lot and I'm trying to optimize few movements I do with too much key pressed.

For exemple I have this :

```
module SanitizeIdsParams
  def self.my_method ids
    ...code
  end
end
```

And I want this

```
module SanitizeIdsParams
  def self.my_method ids
    ...code
  end

  def self.my_method ids
    ...code
  end
end
```

For the moment I'm doing something like `j<CR>v3jy<ESC>4Go<ESC>p` I'm not a huge fan of `:2,4t.4Go<ESC>`, any other ideas without specifying exact line number ?

I would like to know also if when I yank I can stay where I yank and not going at the beginning of my visual selection.

Open to classic vim motions and plugins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have your visual selection you can do:

```
:'<,'>t'>
```

(it's actually `:t'>` because Vim adds the visual range automatically)

to copy it after the visual selection and do:

```
'[O<Esc>
```

to add an empty line.

If you don't want to use visual selection, something like this should work:

```
:,/end/t//
```

You will still need to add the empty line manually.

Comment: t - acronym for copy - see :h copy

Answer (score 3):

For most languages you probably would be able to jump between the start and the end of a block of code with `%` (check `:help %`), because the [matchit plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39) comes installed by default with vim. So on your example you could only navigate to 'begin' or 'end' and use `y%` to copy the entire block.

If you don't need to duplicate all the code, but just want to use as a template, you should check some kind of snippet plugin, such as [Ultisnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715) and [snipmate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540).

Comment: +1 for snipmate even despite your typo!

Answer (score 3):

If you have to copy a known number of lines you can do:

<kbd>3</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>

yanks 3 lines from the cursor position

And use <kbd>p</kbd> to paste where do you want them.

---

It may come as help to use:

```
set relativenumber
```

it will show line numbers relative to cursor position. Show you can see how many lines you need to yank(as far as the display permits).

To turn line numbering off do this:

```
set norelativenumber
```

Comment: thanks. I'm already using relative line number a lot. Thanks for tips.